# Mocha, Electron: Errors in testing

Tags: testing, electron, mocha.js, spectron

I was testing my electron app with mocha and got this error several times (and I'm still getting it!). Every time I run the program it returns with the error

```
 > Executing task: npm run test <


 > forte@1.0.0 test PATH TO PROJECT
 > mocha ./tests/test.js



  0 passing (3ms)

  Test failed Failed to create session.
 unknown error: Chrome failed to start: was killed.
 (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
 (The process started from chrome location \node_modules\spectron\lib\launcher.bat is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is 
 assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Just in case this is important, the part which says `(The process started from chrome location \node_modules...` actually had the whole path, not just that.

In my test.js file I have the code from the spectron home page, which you can view [here](https://www.electronjs.org/spectron). What is wrong with the test files?